# Make attack particles at collision point?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm working on a 2D game, it has some basic combat but I want to spice it up a bit with some effects.

First I added a flash when you get hit but I also wanted to add some particles.
I thought it would be easy and I could just put the particles at the enemy's or player's position. But it didnt look right.

So does anyone know how I can detect the position I collided? I'm using PhysicsOverlapCircleAll to detect the enemys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Physics2D.OverlapCircle` doesn't provide you that information on where exactly the overlap happened.

But there are other options you could do instead:

- Do the collision detection for attacks using rigidbody collisions handled via the [`OnCollisionEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) method. The Collision2D object passed to this method contains an [array of contact positions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D-contacts.html). Handling attacks as a rigidbody hitting other rigidbodies also has the neat effect that it's an easy way to add physically accurate pushback if you want to, which is another way to add more "juice" to a game. (although in a way that is not just cosmetic but actually affects the mechanics of the game)
- After detecting that there is a collision with PhysicsOverlapCircle, use [`Physics2D.ClosestPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.ClosestPoint.html) from the attacker's position to the target collider to get the closest point on the perimeter of their collider.
- After detecting that there is a collision with PhysicsOverlapCircle, use a [`Physics2D.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) from the attacker to the target. The returned RaycastHit2D object contains the [.point](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D-point.html) where the contact occurred. It also provides a [.normal](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D-normal.html) that can be useful for setting the orientation of a hit particle effect.

Comment: Thankyou, I used ClosestPoint as it was easiest for me and it worked perfectly.